# How to get location coordinates?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I wanted to get my current location coordinates and pass it to a String. I've tried to use googleMap.getMyLocation(); but the method is deprecated and it's not really what I need because I need literally the Latitude and Longitude coordinates in a string.
Can anyone help a young programmer :)

Answer (score 1):

See this part of Android's documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html